# Box2D: Making it Determinsitic?

Tags: physics, box2d, synchronization

From articles on the web, I found that floating point math generally has accuracy of at least 6 digits. With this in mind, is it possible to make Box2D which uses floats fully deterministic through the use of heavy rounding (i.e. 1st or 2nd decimal place)?

Comment: The question is why? It produces the same results for the same binary and the same machine. Why would you need more than that?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is an obvious **no** simply because "heavy rounding" doesn't alleviate the problem. Like you suggested the issue is with how floats behave on different architectures.

Lets say you round things up. :)
What happens with very large numbers? They are still exactly the same. Large numbers behave differently too on different architectures. Fractions, are simply large numbers with a different exponent that determines the radix (floating) point position.

You would need to implement a cross-platform number. This is a known and well covered subject. Hint, there are performance issues.